# pass parameters to jquery click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a dynamic html table that gets created from the DB using PHP.  It looks something like:

```
<table id="webcam-table">             
<thead>                 
    <tr>                     
        <th>Camera <br>Type</th>                     
        <th>Name</th>                     
        <th>Quality</th>                     
        <th>Motion <br>Detection</th>                     
        <th>Email <br>Notice</th>                     
        <th>Camera Actions</th>                 
    </tr>             
</thead>                                  
<tbody>                 
    <tr data-hash="6ab000ef7926b4a182f0f864a0d443fc19a29fdd">                     
        <td>WEBCAM</td>                     
        <td>test</td>                     
        <td>HIGH</td>                     
        <td>On</td>                     
        <td>On</td>                     
        <td><button id="editbutton" onClick='edit(this, "/ajax_dash", "WEBCAM", "test29999988877", "0", "6ab000ef7926b4a182f0f864a0d443fc19a29fdd", "0", "0", "1", "", "", "", "")'>Edit</button></td>                 
    </tr>                                  
</tbody>                                                               
<tbody>                 
    <tr data-hash="c0fc37512cdcc49b034fefabdc31bb12a3b618da">                     
        <td>AXIS</td>                     
        <td>mycamera</td>                     
        <td>MEDIUM</td>                     
        <td>On</td>                     
        <td>On</td>                     
        <td><button id="editbutton" onClick='edit(this, "/ajax_dash", "AXIS", "myaxiscameraTESb", "1", "c0fc37512cdcc49b034fefabdc31bb12a3b618da", "0", "0", "0", "hhhhhhhhhjjjkk", "ggyykk", "10.0.0.999", "1111")'>Edit</button>
    </tr>                                                                  
</tbody>   
...                           
</table>
```

If you click on the edit button it opens up a form with all the camera settings already populated so you can then edit them.  I have this working fine in my javascript implementation as just a form.  But I wanted to change this to a jquery dialog.

This is what I have:

```
var js = jQuery.noConflict();
js(function() {    

js( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
height: 300,
width: 350,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "Edit camera settings": function() {
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

    },
    Cancel: function() {
        js( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
},
close: function() {
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
}
});

js( "#editbutton" )
.button()
.click(function() {
    js( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

I have two problems:

1. This only creates the edit button for the first row in the table, how can I apply this to all rows?
2. How can I start passing parameters to the click function so that I can start filling in the form, for example:

   js("input:text").val(cameraname); //although I don't think this is a good idea either as I have many different input text fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple html elements with the same id ( ex: editbutton ). This may be part of the problem with #1, without seeing more of your code.

I would avoid using the inline event handlers ( onClick ) for a number of reasons, but mostly because it's generally considered bad practice these days. More importantly, if a user has a slow connection, they could be clicking the buttons prior to the rest of your code being ready. Depending on the code in the `edit` function, this may be undesirable. Instead, you should use jQuery's `click` method to bind a function to the buttons at DOM ready.

All that being said, I would make your buttons fetch the corresponding data ( either from an array loaded at page load, or via an `$.ajax` call ) based on the `data-hash` value. Then you can pass that data to the form, and pop the dialog.

Array example

```
<!-- php generated javascript delivered at page load -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table_data = [];
    <?php
        foreach($data as $hash => $obj) {
            // assuming $obj is an array of data
            echo "data['$hash'] = [";
            $hash_strings = array();
            foreach($obj as $field => $val) {
                $hash_strings[] = "'$field' => '$val'";
            }
            echo implode(",\n",$hash_strings)."];\n";
        }
    ?>

    $(function) { //DOM Ready

        // Define your dialog, but don't open it yet
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false
            // you can also define your other dialog stuff here, like buttons
            //    and what happens when you click on them
        });

        $('#webcam-table button.edit').click(function() {
            var hash = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-hash');
            for(var i in data[hash]) {
                $('#dialog form input[name="' + i + '"]').val(data[hash][i]);
            }
            $('#dialog').dialog("open");
        }); // End of #webcam-table button.edit click

    }); // End of DOM Ready

</script>
```

Ajax example

```
$(function) { //DOM Ready

    // Define your dialog, but don't open it yet
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false
        // you can also define your other dialog stuff here, like buttons
        //    and what happens when you click on them
    });

    $('#webcam-table button.edit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/get-camera-data-by-hash.php", //returns the form data in json format
            data: "hash=" + $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-hash'),
            success: function(data){
                for(var i in data) {
                    $('#dialog form input[name="' + i + '"]').val(data[i]);
                }
                $('#dialog').dialog("open");
            }
        });
    }); // End of #webcam-table button.edit click

}); // End of DOM Ready
```

Now, this is untested, so there may be some syntax issues, but hopefully it should get you on the right track ( or at least what I consider to be the right track given the information provided ). Also, I'm making some assumptions about the data being returned, etc. You should probably be doing some sanity checks along the way.

Dialog would look something like this:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form>
        <input name="field_one" type="text">
        <input name="field_two" type="text">
        <input name="field_three" type="text">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use ajax at this point because of Joomla reasons, I will research using an array at page load...any tutorial references would be appreciated.  Thx for the response

Comment: Updated the example to include an array example.